# Reason given for rejecting an edit seems innapropriate

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I recently had a suggested edit rejected, which is fine and happens occasionally. When I went to make my next edit, however, it suggested I review why my last one was rejected. The reason was given as "[This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6249743)"

I don't mind my edit being rejected in general, but this reason seems so wildly off. I'm promoting nothing, I'm not vandilising the post. Perhaps the reviewer saw that I'd deleted a lot of text and made this assumption, wheras I was actually just deleting duplicated error messages. The edit was accepted by another reviewer.

I'm not worried about the reputation, which is only 2 points, but I just think it genuinely improves the question. Is there any point or way of contesting it, or should I just take it on the chin?

Comment: The best you'll get is someone saying the rejection is incorrect.  There is nothing for anyone to do with that information though.

Comment: Take it on the chin. At first glance I thought the same as the reviewer. Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: The only think I can say is that your comment was not descriptive enough of what you had actually done, as you have done much more than spelling and grammar so I wonder if you had explained the delete the reviewer would be more understanding to your edit and not rejected

Comment: @Stacker-flow Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @Stacker-flow I think you hit the nail on the head.  If the text was intentionally being removed for a reason, then you should explain that in the edit comment.  Absent an explanation, it just looks like you are removing possibly important text